# Scrapy python change url

Tags: python, json, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape information about doctors. I have the following url but I'd like to keep changing the UserID=99 of the url and save information. I don't know how to put something like a loop that keeps changing the userid in the url and when I do 
`scrapy crawl sch -o items.json -t json` it saves everything into one single JSON File.

```
class DmozSpider(Spider):
    name = "sch"
    allowed_domains = ["qchp.org.qa/en/"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.qchp.org.qa/en/_layouts/SCH_Website/PractitionerDetails.aspx?UserID=990&IsDlg=1"
    ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you want to put, in place of `UserID=990`, the odd numbers from `1` to `100`. Then do:

```
start_urls = []

for i in range(1, 100):
    if i % 2 == 1:
        start_urls.append("http://www.qchp.org.qa/en/_layouts/SCH_Website/PractitionerDetails.aspx?UserID=" + str(i) + "&IsDlg=1")
```

Comment: I get TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just made it str(i).